# monotonicity of a complex function referring normal distribution

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

In my research I need to make clear the following point:

Suppose that a random variable $\theta\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. There are two imperfect signals about $\theta$: $X=\theta+\sigma_x\xi$ and $Y=\theta+\sigma_y\eta$, where $\xi, \eta\sim N(0,1)$, $\sigma_x, \sigma_y>0$, and the three r.v.s $\theta$, $\xi$, and $\eta$ are independent. Now we fix three real numbers $y'$, $y''$, and $\theta^*$ such that $y'<y''$, and consider the posterior belief
$$g(x,y',y'',\theta):=\mathbb P(\theta<\theta^*\,|\,x,y'\le y\le y''),$$
where $x$ is a realization of $X$ and $y$ a realization of $Y$. The interpretation is that we can directly observe the realization of $X$ but for each realization of $Y$ we are only told whether it is in $[y',y'']$ or not.

**Question:** Under what condition does it hold that $\partial g/\partial x\le 0$, that is, when the posterior belief is monotonic in signals?

Can anyone give me some suggestion or hint on that? Currently I have derived an expression for $g$ but it seems impossible to say anything about the monotonicity. The posterior belief is given by
$$g=\frac{\displaystyle\int_{y'}^{y''}\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{\tau_y(\tau_x+\tau)}{2\pi(\tau_x+\tau_y+\tau)}}\exp\left\{-\displaystyle\frac{\bigg(y-\displaystyle\frac{\tau_xx+\tau\mu}{\tau_x+\tau}\bigg)^2}{2\cdot \displaystyle\frac{\tau_x+\tau_y+\tau}{\tau_x\tau_y+\tau\tau_y}}\right\}\Phi\left(\frac{\theta^*-\frac{\tau_xx+\tau_yy+\tau\mu}{\tau_x+\tau_y+\tau}}{(\tau_x+\tau_y+\tau)^{-1/2}}\right)\,\mathrm d y}{\Phi\left(\displaystyle\frac{y''-\frac{\tau_xx+\tau\mu}{\tau_x+\tau}}{\sqrt{\frac{\tau_x+\tau_y+\tau}{\tau_x\tau_y+\tau\tau_y}}}\right)-\Phi\left(\displaystyle\frac{y'-\frac{\tau_xx+\tau\mu}{\tau_x+\tau}}{\sqrt{\frac{\tau_x+\tau_y+\tau}{\tau_x\tau_y+\tau\tau_y}}}\right)},$$
where $\tau_x=\sigma_x^{-2}$, $\tau_y=\sigma_y^{-2}$, and $\tau=\sigma^{-2}$. Notice that the integrand in the numerator is in the form of the product of a cdf and a pdf of normal distributions.

Thanks in advance!